# PHP & MYSQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure it out this simple issue. I have two tables
 1) Services 
 2) Projects

Some projects are using only one service_id (ex: web dev), but other are connected with two or three of them (ex: web dev, branding) and I have only one table call service_id. How can I add more than just one service_id?

Services

[image]

Projects

[image: Projects]

Comment: Using a 3rd table (called "join table"). It essentially only has 2-3 columns: one (rather optional, but still preferable) primary key (`id`) and the 2 foreign keys to your tables (`service_id` and `project_id`).

Comment: Please post table structure as text and not in external images (you can generate the structure from PHPMyAdmin).

Comment: but, for example, I have one project and need 2 service_id: web dev and branding. How can I make it possible? whit the new table I can only assign one more service_id?

Comment: Using 3rd table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ccKep wait, you need to create a table to link Services with Projects.  So your database structure would look like:
[image]

You can then combine as many services to as many projects as you want.  Projects_has_Services contains pairs of (service_id, project_id).

Comment: thanks Nic, and can you give me an example of how can I connect with mysqli? Cause I already made a connection but without the new table, just from services to projects, using the service_id and de project _id. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Easiest to get started: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: And please accept answer if it is ok for you :-)